# Appeal of an edit rejection

Tags: discussion, review

[This answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/142967/151600) was edited in such a way that it removed the context for its comments.  The original answer contained a political spiel.  While political spiels do not belong in answers, and its removal from the post would normally be a good thing;  the original answer was up long-enough that there are comments discussing said political spiel, and these comments do not make sense without that spiel in the answer.

I proposed an [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/129572) to the comment that would re-introduce a neutered version of the original answer's spiel -- just enough to give context to the answer's comments.  However, I don't think many of the reviewers read the edit [history](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/142967/revisions) of that answer or my edit summary, and I think they saw me as unnecessarily injecting my own political opinions into an answer (I don't even agree with said political view -- I'm just trying to maintain the integrity of the original answer.).

I read [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4573) that, in such situations, I should create a question on StackExchange Meta, as a sort of appeal;  so that is what I've done.
So, StackExchange, in light of this information, what is the best way forward?  Should we keep the current edit, or should we restore the context for the comments?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution to the problem of numerous comments on a post discussing content removed from that post *that doesn't belong in that post* is to flag those comments as no longer needed (or perhaps the whole post, explaining that the comments under it need mass removal due to the conversation being obsolete now).

There's no need to edit inappropriate content back into a post just to prevent comments from being obsolete.  Comments are *designed* to go obsolete when the post they're commenting on is improved.

Answer (score 3):

I fully read your edit, and it was not appropriate as an answer - in fact the key bit you edited in (that I removed) was a new question.

Leaving it to be deleted, as @Servy mentioned, would have been the correct action in this case.